# plot multiple density functions in one plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i would like to plot multiple density functions in one matplotlib plot. I am currently using:

```
    def get_probability(self, df):
        df.plot.density()
```

Now i got multiple plots in seperated windows.
How i am able to get multiple density functions in one plot ?

I would be grateful for any help !

Comment: Please provide a more detailed question, and examples of what you tried. What is df ? what is plot ? 
Typically matplotlib can plot multiple function by just performing consecutive plt.plot() calls. Why does this not solve your problem ?

Comment: pandas plot functions are a convenience wrapper for matplotlib functions. You should familiarize yourself with the differences between [figure and axis objects in matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/), predefined an axis object, then plot all density functions into the same axis object.

Answer (score 1):

If you create, or get the current `Axes` object, you can pass that to `plot.density` to plot on the same figure, e.g.,

```
def get_probability(self, df):
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt  # you could add this at the top of your script
    ax = plt.gca()  # get current Axes
    df.plot.density(ax=ax)  # pass it to density
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I solved the problem by using ax objects.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).